# g++ variadic template issue

Tags: c++, g++, variadic-templates

So I gave this program to g++ and clang (both on Linux, x86_64):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<char... Cs>
struct A {
  static const string s;
  static A a;
  ~A() {
    cout << "s = " << s << "\n";
  }
};

template<char... Cs>
const string A<Cs...>::s = {{Cs...}};

template<char... Cs>
A<Cs...> A<Cs...>::a;

int main(void)
{
  (void)A<'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'>::a;

  return 0;
}
```

Clang outputs `s = aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` (as expected).

g++ (versions 5 until 8) outputs `s = s = aaaaaaaa` (pretty unexpected).

This doesn't happen if you don't use the variadic template (if you remove all the <> code and inline the character list to initialize `A::s`.

It also doesn't happen if you replace the `std::string` by a character array (and use `A<Cs...>::s = {Cs...}` instead).

Is this code not meant to be, or is it a compiler bug?

Comment: I got "s = aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" with g++7.3.  What version of g++ are you using?  It's probably a bug.

Comment: I get random garbage with gcc 8. Interesting.

Comment: My g++7.3 doesn't give me that. --version says "g++-7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3~16.04.1) 7.3.0".

Comment: If the string is not static, you get the expected behavior. Hmm....

Comment: However, it works when the string fits in the SSO buffer. So quite certainly some lifetime issue.

Comment: Maybe the order of static members... calling the destructor of `static A a;` is printed the content of a destroyed static `s` (if I'm not wrong). Nice question, anyway.

Comment: @max66 But it's just one translation unit; `A::s` should be constructed first and thus destructed last, shouldn't it?

Comment: @BaummitAugen - well... I remember only the (direct) order of contructions; is normative that the order of destruction is inverse?

Comment: @max66 If I'm not completely mistaken, I think two static objects in the same translation unit should be constructed in order of definition.

Comment: Btw, you forgot to `#include <string>`, but that's not the actual issue.

Comment: Order of destruction differs between clang and gcc [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c95cdc909faf844). [Demo with constructor](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69a1f6d964befcc4)

Comment: My g++ versions (both 7 and 8) are on the mac, and show what was expected, with or without optimizations.  Weird.

Comment: Btw, looks like I was completely mistaken lol. Only for templates, at least.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is incorrect. The important part of the standard is 6.6.3/1 [basic.start.dynamic]
in N4659:

> Dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with static storage duration is unordered if the variable is an
>   implicitly or explicitly instantiated specialization [...]

Because the initialization is not ordered, you cannot rely on the order of destruction. Any order is legal, regardless of order of construction. See 6.6.4/3 [basic.start.term]

gcc is thus allowed to destroy `s` before it destroys `a`,
which is what happens and causes the weird output. [Live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nREnRe1D8uKCvgU7).

Comment: Unspecified order... wow... I would never said that. This can explain everything.

Comment: Do you know *why* such a rule exist?

Comment: @Passerby Not for certain, but the reason is probably the fact they exist conditionally. So from  the definitions alone, you cannot tell what specializations will actually end up existing, so I guess they did not want to force the compilers to keep track of that.